# Conflict between expl3.sty and breqn

Tags: incompatibility, expl3, breqn

I've encountered some problems using the **breqn**-package. I've allready read most of the topics on this forum about breqn but didn't find a solution.
When I use the breqn-package, the log-file produces many errors **in the expl3.sty** file, all of the form:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filename
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."
```

I'm already using the latest version of the packages, so that should not be the problem. I'm also using other packages:
amsmath, amsfonts, subcaption and float.
I've also tried the solution proposed in the topic "Naming equations with breqn", namely adding the provisional code:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn  
\cs_set_eq:NN \int_eval:w \__int_eval:w  
\cs_set_eq:NN \int_eval_end: \__int_eval_end:  
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

in the preamble, but is doesn't work.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

P.S. If this information isn't sufficient to solve the problem, just ask and I'll put the entire file online.

Here is the .log file that is produced

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.2.4)  20 MAR 2013 15:12
entering extended mode
**BeginThesis.tex

("C:\Users\Laptop Michael\Desktop\Schooljunk\Thesis\Alles tot nu toe in Latex\B
eginThesis.tex"
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman, ngerman, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, french, dutch, loaded
.
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count88
\Gm@cntv=\count89
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count90
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
 (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\latin1.def
File: latin1.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen111
))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen112
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count92
\leftroot@=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count94
\DOTSCASE@=\count95
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen113
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count96
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count97
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count98
\dspbrk@lvl=\count99
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count100
\column@=\count101
\maxfields@=\count102
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen114
\alignsep@=\dimen115
\tagshift@=\dimen116
\tagwidth@=\dimen117
\totwidth@=\dimen118
\lineht@=\dimen119
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty
\bigstrutjot=\dimen120
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen121
\WF@size=\dimen122
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count103
\WF@box=\box28
\WF@everypar=\toks23
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\eurosym\eurosym.sty
Package: eurosym 1998/08/06 v1.1 European currency symbol ``Euro''
\@eurobox=\box29
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\dutch.ldf
Language: dutch 2005/03/30 v3.8i Dutch support from the babel system
 (C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count104
\U@D=\dimen123
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 132.
)) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count105
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen124
\Gin@req@width=\dimen125
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/02/03 v3.3-65 Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/02/03 v1.5-62 caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen126
\captionmargin@=\dimen127
\captionwidth=\dimen128
\caption@tempdima=\dimen129
\caption@indent=\dimen130
\caption@parindent=\dimen131
\caption@hangindent=\dimen132
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count106
Package caption Info: wrapfig package is loaded.
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\caption\subcaption.sty
Package: subcaption 2013/02/03 v1.1-62 Sub-captions (AR)
\c@subfigure=\count107
\c@subtable=\count108
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\float\float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count109
\float@exts=\toks24
\float@box=\box30
\@float@everytoks=\toks25
\@floatcapt=\box31
)
("C:\Users\Laptop Michael\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\mh\breqn.sty"
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\expl3.sty (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2012/07/16 v3991 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filename 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...e \@cls@pkg \space provides `\filename 
                                                  '\@gobble \on@line .
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `expl3',
               but the package provides `'.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filedate 
                      v\fileversion  \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filedate  v\fileversion 
                                     \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...te  v\fileversion  \filedescription 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> Package: \@gtempa \space \filedate 
                                            v\fileversion  \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...gtempa \space \filedate  v\fileversion 
                                                   \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...edate  v\fileversion  \filedescription 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Package:   v 
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count110
) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2012/11/24 v4339 L3 Basic definitions

! Undefined control sequence.
l.483 \tex_ifodd:D \l@expl@log@functions@bool

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \etex_protected:D 
l.484   \cs_set_protected:Npn
                              \__chk_if_free_cs:N #1
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2012/08/28 v4149 L3 Argument expansion
)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2012/11/24 v4339 L3 Token lists
)

! LaTeX Error: File `l3intexpr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.83 \RequirePackage
                    { 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5187 strings out of 495223
 74929 string characters out of 3180905
 125786 words of memory out of 3000000
 8359 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 54 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,0n,38p,296b,45s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: It looks like you have a file version mismatch. Can you edit in your `.log` file?

Comment: No, i'm not able to edit in the Log file (if with .log file you mean the error file that is produced when building).

Comment: TeX produces a `.log` file when it runs: that is where the error you see is listed. I'm guessing you have a _very_ old version of one file and much newer versions of others. I'll need to see the `.log` file to be user. If you can't edit it in, e-mail it to me: `joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk`.

Comment: I've copied the .log file in the question, I hope this is what you needed to see...

Comment: @User45 I have `l3bootstrap 2013/01/08 v4420`, so you'd better update the `l3` packages and try again. Let's see if the problem is only here.

Comment: When I try to update files with the 'Update' module form MikTex, it says that 'there are currently no updates available' (as I've already updated this morning).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You need to update both as a 'regular' user and as Admin: you've got files in both modes in your log.

Comment: Okay, done that. This seems to have solved some problems but now the Tex is failing to compile the document. I only get the following message when I press 'built':

Comment: Process started

    Running miktex-pdftex.exe...